# How can I remove the particular line in crontab?

Tags: linux, bash, shell

below mentioned script has my crontab running functions.

```
# Chef Name: binary_log_purge 0 */4 * * * /engineyard/bin/binary_log_purge -q
# Chef Name: database_oom_score
*/30 * * * * /engineyard/bin/database_oom_adj
# Chef Name: logrotate -f /etc/logrotate.d/stats 0 * * * * logrotate -f /etc/logrotate.d/stats
# Chef Name: cpu_utilaisation
*/5 * * * * cd /tmp && sh cpu_util.sh >> cpu_utilaisation.log
# Chef Name: Test_script
*/2 * * * * cd /tmp && sh test.sh >> tests_cript.log
```

The above mentioned query i want to remove the blow line

```
# Chef Name: Test_script
*/2 * * * * cd /tmp && sh test.sh >> tests_cript.log
```

How can i remove the function with below mentioned steps:

Step 1 : first i want to find the below line is there or not. How can i find out?

```
*/2 * * * * cd /tmp && sh test.sh >> tests_cript.log
```

Step 2 : If the line is there. I want to remove the function. How can i remove the function ?

Please help me.....

Comment: related https://askubuntu.com/questions/408611/how-to-remove-or-delete-single-cron-job-using-linux-command

Answer (score 3, accepted):

According to `man 5 crontab` the crontab files are not intended to be edited directly.

What you can do is run `crontab -l`, filter out the line using `grep -v`,
run `crontab -r` to clear the crontab then pipe the modified version of the crontab file into `crontab -`.

Comment: `crontab` also "honors" the `$EDITOR` env var (when set), which is typically set to `vi` (or possibly `emacs`). So assuming you know how to use `vi` you can edit the current user's entry's just by typing `crontab`. Good luck to all.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `grep -A 1 'Chef Name: Test_script' | grep -v "^#"` to get the line after Test_script but ignoring commented out lines.